# How to set string default value of a column in TypeORM migration

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to set the default value of a column as 'Canada/Eastern' and set it to not null. Here is what the column looks like:

```
queryRunner.addColumn('users', new TableColumn({
    name: 'timezone_name',
    type: 'character varying',
    default: '"Canada/Eastern"',
    isNullable: false,
  }));
```

Its giving me an error:

```
query failed: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "timezone_name" character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT "Canada/Eastern"
error: error: column "Canada/Eastern" does not exist
```

Answer (score 4):

Using "'Canada/Eastern'" fixes the error

```
queryRunner.addColumn('users', new TableColumn({
    name: 'timezone_name',
    type: 'character varying',
    default: "'Canada/Eastern'",
    isNullable: false,
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove isNullable and Try below code

```
queryRunner.addColumn('users', new TableColumn({
    name: 'timezone_name',
    type: 'character varying',
    default: '"Canada/Eastern"'
  }));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).